# how to run a shell script as an alias?

Tags: shell, scripting, alias

I wanna alias a script to my zsh. Aliasing a script in zshrc does not work, the output of the script in nothing

There are no syntax errors in my script. i have tried running 
"sh ./script.sh" in the script containing folder which does fetches the desired result but alias something="sh ~/script.sh" does not work
even alias something="source ~/script.sh" does not work

**the script creates a local project and a github repo**

contents of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function create () {
    read -p 'Repository Name: ' uservar
    projects_directory = ~/Downloads/Projects/ #change this path to the directory where you want to store you files
    mkdir $projects_directory/$uservar
    cd $projects_directory/$uservar
    git init
    touch README.md 
    echo -e "#$uservar" >> $projects_directory/$uservar/README.md

    # this is where we make a github repo from cli
    repo_name=$uservar
    test -z $repo_name && echo "Repo name required." 1>&2 && exit 1
    curl -u 'thisisshub' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "{\"name\":\"$repo_name\"}" #change thisisshub to your <username> 
    #making a git repo from cli ends

    git add .
    git commit -m "Initial Commit"
    git push -u origin master
    code .
}
```

expected result: successful aliasing of a script

actual result: no output

Comment: This just makes a function. Where do you call the function?

Comment: What is `code`?

Comment: "There are no syntax errors in my script". How do you know?

Comment: `source ~/script; function`, by contrast, would actually run the function.

Comment: @ClaytonL The code block is indented, no need to add triple backticks around it.